# Elasticsearch bool query_string for partial and full text matching

Tags: elasticsearch

I am attempting to create an Elasticsearch query that will perform a partial and full text match on two fields `name` and `type` in my index and return all matches that contain a specific `uid` field value. As example, I have the following records:

- `{ name: "Doug", "type": "Large"}`
- `{ name: "Doug Small", "type":"Large"}`
- `{ name: "Smal", "type": "Medium"}`
- `{ name: "Peter", "type": "Small"}`

I would like my query to match and return all of these records. Here is my query so far:

```html
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "type"
            ],
            "query": "*Doug Small*~",
            "default_operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "uid": "123"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In order to get any results to return I had to wrap the query in `*` and also add the fuzzy `~` at the end. Is this the right type of query for this use case?

Here is my mapping:

```html
{
  "test": {
    "mappings": {
      "data": {
        "properties": {
          "uid": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please share your mapping as well

Comment: @AlkisKalogeris mapping has been added. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems to consider here.

1. Do not use [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html), unless you know exactly what you are doing. Pay special attention if the input is coming from the user. Prefer to use [simple_query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html) instead.
2. I doubt that you want the name to be of type `keyword`. This type means that the string will not be analyzed (lowercased, tokenized etc). So if you search with something other than the exact same input then it won't match. e.g. `Doug Small`. You would think that since you search with the exact same input, at least this document would return, but that's not the case. The reason is that `query_string` or `simple_query_string` input is parsed (and as a consequence tokenized). If you don't specify your input as one term then it won't match. In order to do that you need to wrap your term with double quotes ("*\"Doug Small\"*"). But if you do this, you will lose all other matches.
3. I believe what you need is the name and type to be of type `text`. This means that the saved string will be analyzed (tokenized, lowercased etc, check [simple analyzer (which is the default if you don't specify another)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html).
4. You have operator specified as `AND` for `query_string`. This means that all of the query terms must match on either name or type. But you are stating that you need to have all documents returned with your query. Only one document has both `Doug` and `Small`. If you need this then that operator must change to `OR` (which is the default).

A complete example

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "uid": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
POST test/_bulk
{ "index" : { "_id" : "1" } }
{ "name": "Doug", "type": "Large"}
{ "index" : { "_id" : "2" } }
{ "name": "Doug Small", "type":"Large"}
{ "index" : { "_id" : "3" } }
{ "name": "Smal", "type": "Medium"}
{ "index" : { "_id" : "4" } }
{ "name": "Peter", "type": "Small"}
```

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "type"
            ],
            "query": "*Doug Small*",
            "default_operator": "OR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above query now returns all three documents that have `Doug` or `Small` or both. Moreover, is case insensitive (since it's now analyzed) so this `*doug small*` will yield the same 3 results.

Since now the fields are analyzed you don't need to use the wildcard symbol, because it is now for the first token and the last. Meaning

- `*Doug Small*`: Match anything that has `<ANYTHING>Dog` OR `Small<Anything>`
- `*Doug Smith Small*`: Match anything that has `<ANYTHING>Dog` OR `Smith` OR `Small<Anything>` (OR -> default operator, if you keep AND then it changes accordingly)

So let's remove the wildcard as well

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "type"
            ],
            "query": "Doug Small",
            "default_operator": "OR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This yields the exact same 3 results. You are still missing `Smal`. Now you need to add fuzzy matching in order to include that as well.

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "type"
            ],
            "query": "Doug Small~",
            "default_operator": "OR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This `Doug Small~` means bring everything that has `Doug` OR `Small` where `Small` can be a NOT exact match.

You can have fuzzy matching for all your terms

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "type"
            ],
            "query": "Dg~ Small~",
            "default_operator": "OR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The reason why `Dg` matches with `Doug` is because of the fuziness level https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness

> The maximum allowed Levenshtein Edit Distance (or number of edits)